# Setting up gulp-express

Tags: express, gulp

I'm developing an Express.js app, I'm looking for ways to restart the Express.js app with LiveReload capabilities.

I've found a gulp plugin called [gulp-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-express), I tried to setup *gulpfile.js* as shown below

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var express = require('gulp-express');

gulp.task('express', function() {
    express.run(['app.js']);

    gulp.watch(['app.js', 'routes/**/*.js'], [express.run]);
});
```

With this *gulpfile.js*, gulp offers to restart the Express.js app whenever I edit the .js files

But no LiveReload capabilities at all, I read from the documentation and tried to edit *gulpfile.js* with `gulp.watch(['app.js', 'routes/**/*.js'], [express.run, express.notify]);`, unfortunately this causes a gulp error when I edit the .js files

How do I configure *gulpfile.js* for both restarting the Express.js app and LiveReload capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
express.run(['app.js'],{},35729);
```

And don't forget add:

```
var app = module.exports.app = exports.app = express();

app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
```

to app.js